# Gtest Git, Testing Git functionality using Gtest

Tags: unit-testing, googletest

In my app, I need to connect to some git repo and perform action based on given commit/hash of the git-repo. Code snip could be as below

```
func App_DoSomething(hash, file string) {
    
    git.GetContentAtHash(file, hash, content)
    App_DoSomethingWithContent(content)
}
```

Now I want to test GIT functionality  of the above code using GTEST ( assume code is written in C/C++). So far I have a local archived git repo embedded in the code, which get extracted in local FS during gtest environment setup and then git-functionality unit test are run.

Is there a better way of doing things ? At runtime, I could have create git-repo and used it, but that can probably bring different behavior on each run.  Is there any package which I could directly use ?

I don't want to mock GIT functionality as it beat purpose, Certainly I can mock APP functionality but that's question for other day.

Answer (score 0):

To close here, I ended up archiving a demo test repo along with my test code, On gtest setup I do needful to extract the archive and setup the git-repo, and clone using FS/SSH/https